# I get an mysqlclient error when run migration in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x

I install Django and try to connect to MySQL and run migrations, i get error "Did you install mysqlclient?".

What should I do?

I'm using venv, and my python version is 3.7.4, and mysql is Ver 8.0.17 for osx10.14 on x86_64 (Homebrew).
And this is pip list

```
Package             Version    
------------------- -----------
beautifulsoup4      4.6.0      
certifi             2019.6.16  
chardet             3.0.4      
Django              2.2.5      
django-modelcluster 4.4        
django-taggit       0.24.0     
django-treebeard    4.3        
djangorestframework 3.10.2     
draftjs-exporter    2.1.6      
entrypoints         0.3        
flake8              3.7.4      
html5lib            1.0.1      
idna                2.8        
mccabe              0.6.1      
mysqlclient         1.4.2.post1
Pillow              6.1.0      
pip                 19.0.3     
pycodestyle         2.5.0      
pyflakes            2.1.1      
pytz                2019.2     
requests            2.22.0     
setuptools          40.8.0     
six                 1.12.0     
sqlparse            0.3.0      
Unidecode           1.1.1      
urllib3             1.25.3     
wagtail             2.6.1      
wagtailcodeblock    1.15.0.0   
webencodings        0.5.1      
Willow              1.1
```

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'local_test',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',
        }
    }
}
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bicepper/PycharmProjects/test-project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
  File "/Users/bicepper/PycharmProjects/test-project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/bicepper/PycharmProjects/test-project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/bicepper/PycharmProjects/test-project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/bicepper/PycharmProjects/test-project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/bicepper/PycharmProjects/test-project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/bicepper/PycharmProjects/test-project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/bicepper/PycharmProjects/test-project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/bicepper/PycharmProjects/test-project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/bicepper/PycharmProjects/test-project/test/base/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from modelcluster.models import ClusterableModel
  File "/Users/bicepper/PycharmProjects/test-project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modelcluster/models.py", line 153, in <module>
    class ClusterableModel(models.Model):
  File "/Users/bicepper/PycharmProjects/test-project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 117, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/bicepper/PycharmProjects/test-project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/bicepper/PycharmProjects/test-project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Users/bicepper/PycharmProjects/test-project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/bicepper/PycharmProjects/test-project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/bicepper/PycharmProjects/test-project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Users/bicepper/PycharmProjects/test-project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 20, in <module>
    ) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

Comment: Did you Fix it?
I am getting the same error, I can start my django server but I cannot make any migrations.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `mysqlclient`, which you can install with `pip install mysqlclient`.

Make sure that you are working in a virtual environment, and you probably shouldn't use `mysqlclient` and `mysql-python` in the same environment, or there might be issues (I'm not sure though).

I've never used `mysql-python`, so I can't say much about that package.

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed that I am in a virtual environment and mysqlclient is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Activate venv and run `pip install mysql-python`. Make sure you did `pip install -U pip` withing venv before installing `mysql-python` library.

Comment: Another error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'` has occurred.It seems that `mysql-python` does not support python3.